# Get mifare card serial number is incorrect

Tags: c#, rfid, mifare, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

With the card reader I'm using, the protocol to retrieve the serial number of a MIFARE card is as follows:

> Mifare anticollision, `0x0202`:
>   Function card anticollision
>   Format       `aa bb 05 00 00 00 02 02 00`
>   Response  `aa bb 0a 00 52 51 02 02 00 46 ff a6 b8 a4`

Where `46 ff a6 b8` is the card serial number in the above response.

I implement this protocol in C# as follows:

```
private SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();
private string _receivedData = null;

public MifareCardReader(string comPort, int baudRate)
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    _serialPort.PortName = comPort;
    _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
    _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
    _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    _serialPort.Open();   

    // Add event
    _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;     
}

public string MifareAnticollision()
{
    if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        string message = "AABB050000000202000D";
        byte[] data = StringToByteArray(message);
        _serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    _receivedData += _serialPort.ReadExisting();
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(receivedData);
    if (data.Length >= 9)
    {
        if (data[8] == 0) // OK
        {
            // Response data is complete
            if (data.Length == 14)
            {
                StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(8);
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", data[9]);
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", data[10]);
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", data[11]);
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", data[12]);

                string cardID = hex.ToString();
                _receivedData = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        else // fail
        {
            _receivedData = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this with 3 different MIFARE cards, however, the output is not what I expected:

- Card 1: received: `3F463F3F`, expected: `974682D6`
- Card 2: received: `3F450B3F`, expected: `EA450B91`
- Card 3: received: `070D3F3F`, expected: `070DEBD6`

What do I need to change to get the correct output?

Comment: but what is your question?

Comment: I did exactly as protocol but not gotten proper card serial number. I don't know why. My algorithm is wrong or protocol is missing???

Comment: ok so you have bad output, just give me 3 examples of your input as hex values and output that u want to get and i will fix it for u:) Card3: 070D3F3F is bad output? or it is input?

Comment: What is the thing you are speaking to via the serial port?

Comment: If it is [this](http://www.accxproducts.com/wiki/images/2/27/YLMF507A_protocol.pdf) reader. Why are you not using the combined "Mifare S50 select a card ( Request + anticollision + select) 0x0200" command? I have no experience with this particular reader, but generally `REQA` (in your case the command 0x0201) should precede `CL1` (in your case the command 0x0202).

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are experiencing seems to be that bytes with a value above `0x7F` replaced with `0x3F` (the question mark ("?") character). I.e. only 7-bit values show correctly and values with the 8th bit set are turned into "?" (`0x3F`). E.g. for card 1, `974682D6` is "received" as `3F463F3F`, because `0x97`, `0x82`, and `0xD6` have their 8th bit set.

The source for this problem is that you are using the `ReadExisting()` method to read a string value from the serial port. By default, the `ReadExisting()` reads bytes from the serial port, translates them using the ASCII encoding (`System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`), and returns the resulting string. You then take that string and convert it back to a byte array (again using the ASCII encoding).

The problematic steps are the conversions using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`/`Encoding.ASCII`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Because ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, ASCII characters are **limited to the lowest 128** Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F. *[...]* characters outside that range are **replaced with a question mark (?)** before the encoding operation is performed.

Consequently, you should read the bytes directly into a byte array using the `Read()` or `ReadByte()` methods. E.g. with

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
int bytesRead = _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```